# Why can't I add the nms_threshold in a face detection code?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, object-detection, face-detection

I added an NMS code onto a face detection code in Google Colabs so that it won't show a lot of bounding boxes saying 'face' but it said that the required argument 'nms_threshold' is missing even though I had defined it.
Here's the code up to where the error happened

```
import cv2
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

theImage ='drive/MyDrive/07_face_detect/images/twelve-girls.jpg'

theDetectorProto = 'drive/MyDrive/07_face_detect/net_models/face_detector/deploy.prototxt'  # model architect
theDetectorModel = 'drive/MyDrive/07_face_detect/net_models/face_detector/res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel' # weight
theConfidence = 0.2  # minimum probability of detection to be a face
nms_threshold = theNMSThreshold  # minimum pixels to be a face
theNMSThreshold = 0.4

detector = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(theDetectorProto, theDetectorModel)

theTextFont = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
theTextBottomLeft = (10, 100)
theTextScale = 0.85
theTextColor = (255, 0, 255)  # RGB value
theTextThickness = 2  # text line width

image = cv2.imread(theImage) # read as a numpy array, Blue, Green, Red (BGR)
(h, w) = image.shape[:2]
img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) # convert BGR to RGB
plt.imshow(img_rgb) # plot image

imageBlob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(cv2.resize(image, (300, 300)), 1.0, (300, 300)
        ,(104.0, 177.0, 123.0), swapRB=False, crop=False)

detector.setInput(imageBlob)
detections = detector.forward()

    for i in range(0, detections.shape[2]):
    #extract the confidence (i.e., probability) associated with the prediction
    prob = detections[0, 0, i, 2]
    # filter out weak detections
    if prob > theConfidence:
        # compute the (x, y) coordinates of the bounding box for the face
        box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
        (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")
        # extract the face ROI
        face = image[startY:endY, startX:endX]
        
        # ensure the face width and height are sufficiently large
        if fW < theNMSThreshold or fH < theNMSThreshold:
            continue
        

indices = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(box, prob, theNMSThreshold)  
print(indices)
```

And here's the photo I used in my code:
[twelve-girls.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZUAC.jpg)

Comment: `nms_threshold = theNMSThreshold`  # Remove this line.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, the problem is in the following lines:

```
nms_threshold = theNMSThreshold  # minimum pixels to be a face
theNMSThreshold = 0.4
```

You are trying to set the value of variable `nms_threshold` to the same value as the variable `theNMSThreshold`. However, you only instantiate `theNMSThreshold` in the next line. This is what leads to the error message, and it's redundant, too. Just change it as follows, and you should be good to go:

```
nms_threshold = 0.4  # minimum pixels to be a face
```

P.S. [NMS](https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/config.html#yaml-config-references:%7E:text=_C.MODEL.ROI_HEADS.NMS_THRESH_TEST%20%3D%200.5) does not mean minimum pixels to be something, as in your comments. it means boxes with IoU >= this threshold are going to be suppressed i.e. not considered if they overlap more than x%